# Pasting Values Only For Certain Formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large workbook that pulls in weekly data (columns) for hundreds of metrics on several tabs.  It pulls this data in via `SUMIFS` formulas, and on most tabs there are several rows that contain ratios/rates calculated from these `SUMIFS` formulas.

Here is a toy example.
[image]

For each sheet, I would like to paste values only for formulas that are based on 'SUMIFS', and leave the other calculations. I was able to select a range and loop cell-by-cell to accomplish this, but it takes a long time due to the size of the workbook.  Is there a way to do this at once in a batch-fashion?  Basically, I want to copy and paste-values only if a certain condition exists.

Comment: Please share your current loop.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `For each sheet, I would like to paste values only for formulas that are based on 'SUMIFS', and leave the other calculations.` and `Is there a way to do this at once in a batch-fashion? Basically, I want to copy and paste-values only if a certain condition exists.`. In order to correctly understand about your current situation and goal, can you provide your current script and the image of output you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike My goal is to have cells C2:C3 and C6:C7 to be values while keeping the formulas in C10:C11.  However I need to do this in a large scale (multiple columns and rows, the placement of the formulas is different on each page, so I am hoping for a general macro that can select a range and paste values only for cells that contain `SUMIFS`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

**Updated - Slight improvement to make it faster by [Iamblichus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus).**

I am not quite sure what you have tried so far, but this one works relatively fast for a couple of sheets:

```
function myFunction() {

let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'].map(sh=>ss.getSheetByName(sh));  
 
sheets.forEach(sh=>{ 
 let range = sh.getDataRange();
 let formula = range.getFormulasR1C1();
 let values = range.getValues();
 formula.forEach( (fr,fx) => 
 {fr.forEach((fc,fy)=>{
 let outR=sh.getRange(fx+1,fy+1);
 if (fc.toUpperCase().includes('SUMIFS')) outR.setValue(values[fx][fy]);
 })})});

}
```

Please adjust `['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3']` to your needs.

---

### Explanation:

I am iterating through each sheet and I am checking whether the cells contain `SUMIFS` formula or not. If they do, I overwrite them with their value, otherwise I keep their formula.

Comment: Appreciate the effort, unfortunately this does not scale well for large sheets that contain thousands of cells (50-60 rows by 40 columns).  Might still be the best solution, so will mark it if no other replies arrive.

Comment: @rtenha I guess you can split the work. Apply the solution for half of the sheets and when it finishes, do it for the rest. Or you can split it even more. You can set up a trigger to run the different batches. One trigger for the 1st set of sheets and the second trigger for the 2nd set of sheets.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to use `outR.setFormula(fc)` if the formula doesn't include `SUMIFS`. I'd consider changing the last line to `if (fc.toUpperCase().includes('SUMIFS')) outR.setValue(values[fx][fy])`. What do you think of that?

Comment: @Iamblichus thanks, it was a very good idea. I overlooked it, because initially I was trying to build a new array and I wanted all the values. But by using a `forEach` loop it is reduntant to overwrite a formula with exactly the same formula. I hope this will speed up a little bit the process. But if you have any more suggestions, please feel free to post an answer and I will upvote it :)